# Non static method 'getLibroInfo' should not be called statically

Tags: php, php7

```html
<?php
    class Libro
    {
        public $nomlib;
        public $numisbn;
        public $nomautor;
        public $editorial;

        function __construct($nomlib,$numisbn,$nomautor,$editorial)
        {
            $this->nomlib = $nomlib;
            $this->numisbn = $numisbn;
            $this->nomautor =$nomautor;
            $this->editorial=$editorial;
            
        }

        //método para la info
        public function getLibroInfo()
        {
             "El nombre libro es: ".$this->nomlib."<br>";
            "El nombre del Autor del libro es: ".$this->nomautor."<br>";
            "La editorial del libro es: ".$this->editorial."<br>";
            "El numero de ISBN es: ".$this->numisbn."<br>";
        }
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

</form>
<?php

    require_once "libro.php";
    $libronuevo = new libro("ftsgbcehc",4545,"fsbchdv","jhfehbefnhe");
     echo Libro:: getLibroInfo();

?>
```

Al llamar a la funcion getlibtoinfo genera el siguiente error cuando "Non static method 'getLibroInfo' should not be called statically." como se puede llamar la función getlibroinfo sin que salte ese error
y ¿por que se genera ese error?.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de tu clase, tienes este método:

```
public function getLibroInfo()
```

El cual estás tratando de invocar de esta forma:

```
Libro:: getLibroInfo();
```

Lo cual es incorrecto, debido a que el método no es [estático](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php), es decir no tiene esta sintaxis dentro de la clase:

```
public static function getLibroInfo()
```

Lo que debes hacer, es que una vez que ya tienes la instancia de tu clase `libro` en el objeto `$libronuevo` accedas a el (*el método*) a través de esta sintaxis: `$objeto->metodo()` qwuedando de esta forma:

```
require_once "libro.php";
$libronuevo = new libro("ftsgbcehc",4545,"fsbchdv","jhfehbefnhe");
echo Libro->getLibroInfo();
```

Por otro lado debes considerar que si continuas usando el [operador de resolución de ámbito](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) entonces:

- El método debe ser declarado como `static`
- No generarás una instancia de la clase en un objeto
- Accederás con la sintaxis de `clase::metodo();`

Con una sintaxis similar a este ejemplo:

```
<?php

class Stack
{
    public static function over()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


echo Stack::over();
```

Comment: Pero al poner public static function getLibroInfo() sale que el static no usa el $this

Comment: Puedes declarar a las variables como estáticas también y acceder a ellas como: `self::$propiedad` el `self` es para indicar que accedemos a una propiedad estática que esta dentro del mismo contexto de la clase donde la invocamos @CristhianChavezAlonso

Comment: @CristhianChavezAlonso si esa no es la intención entonces con hacer la primer parte de mi respuesta alcanza y no modificas a las propiedades, es decir accediendo al método con: `->`

Comment: OJO: las clases, métodos y/o propiedades estáticas tienen un uso muy específico y no conviene abusar de ellos. Como su nombre lo indica, son elementos estáticos, no cambiantes. Un ejemplo de algo estático sería el PI, que siempre vale `3.14` o cosas como el IVA. Un método como `getLibroInfo()` no debería ser estático ni la clase tampoco.

Comment: Lo sé @A.Cedano y estoy de acuerdo contigo, la intención solo es que viera como usarlo